# How to work with dat.gui or three.js for multiple images?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, three.js, dat.gui

I am working on dat.gui/three.js apis currently. I am getting the examples for single image(https://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#1--Basic-Usage) using the above apis, but how can I work with multiple images so that I can apply respective settings(adding colors, creating folders, giving some input values for each image) using dat.gui or three.js ?

Comment: So what are you asking specifically?

Comment: what is a `single image` and what are `multiple images`?

Comment: Hi, means, How to implement the example(https://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#4--Color-Controllers) on multiple images(I have five images: I can apply this   color settings on one image using above example(First  image), but I want to apply the  same color settings on different/multiple images(For other images) on Submit button or onChange for  each image. I have created fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/phrqafpy/ . Please help me.